# Select class that does not begin with string

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to select a child element that does not contain a class that begins with `z-depth-`:

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="well"></div>
</div>
```

So that if the inner .well also contained a class like `z-depth-1` it would not be selected.

This isn't working because the inner .well is always selected:

```
.well .well:not([class^="z-depth-"])
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: `.well:not([class^="z-depth-"])` should work if the first class is `z-depth-*`

Comment: "This isn't working" is not really a great problem statement. It would be better to show us an example that demonstrates the problem, rather than making answerers (like Sergey below) make up problems you might be facing.

Comment: The "isn't working" is the "what have you tried" part of the question. The problem has been stated in the previous sentence.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You **can't** *select a child element that does not contain a class that begins with `z-depth-`* with **CSS**, you can only:

1. Select all the child elements whose `class` attribute's values don't start from `z-depth-` substring:

```css
.well .well:not([class^="z-depth-"]) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="well z-depth-1">Parent div
    <div class="z-depth-2 well">First child div</div>
    <div class="well z-depth-3">Second child div</div>
</div>
```

2. Select all the child elements whose `class` attribute's values don't contain `z-depth-` substring:

```css
.well .well:not([class*="z-depth-"]) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="well z-depth-1">Parent div
    <div class="z-depth-2 well">First child div</div>
    <div class="well z-depth-3">Second child div</div>
    <div class="well">Third child div</div>
</div>
```

You also could read more about all CSS Selectors on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectors#Selectors_article_overview).

Comment: No way to target the child .well, specifically?

Comment: @RegularEverydayNormalGuy the last example targets the child `.well`, what do you mean?

Comment: I've updated the question explaining it better. Thanks for your effort so far.

Comment: @RegularEverydayNormalGuy I've updated the answer, check out it, please.

Comment: Oh, it ends up it was my understanding of the `[class^="string"]` selector - it doesn't target classes that begin with "string", but elements whose class atribute starts with "string". Using * instead of ^ solved the problem. Many thanks.

Comment: @RegularEverydayNormalGuy yeah, I'm glad to help! All attribute selectors are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Answer (score 6):

You will need to combine `^=` and `*=` to get the desired result.

```css
.well:not([class^="z-depth-"]) { /*will ignore elements if the first class is z-depth-* */
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.well:not([class*=" z-depth-"]) { /*will ignore elements if z-depth-* is second class or later */
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="z-depth-1 well">z-depth-1 well</div>
<div class="well z-depth-1">well z-depth-1</div>
```

Here's a [nice guide](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/) on how to use attributes selectors.

Comment: Your answer together with the selected one helped pointing me to the right direction. It was indeed my understanding of the "^" symbol. `.well .well:not([class*="z-depth-"])` worked. Thank you too.